# Mongo embedded doc POJO: HashSet vs ArrayList

Tags: java, mongodb, collections, pojo

Let say, each Track has subset of Categories.

```
@Document    
public class Track {
        String name;
        HashSet<Category> categories;
        ...
    }


@Document
public class Category {
            String name;
        ...
        }
```

What is the best collection to use?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your criteria.

ArrayList will be a bit faster and use less memory in the loaded Java object. It will keep the order of elements.

HashSet will enforce uniqueness, be faster to check contains, unordered.

It's essentially the same question as which one to use when not using MongoDB...